# Why can't i use PHP Carbon library without installing using composer?

Tags: php, php-carbon

So i have tried to simply include Carbon into my project by simply requiring the autoload.php file in the Carbon package, but then it tells me "symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php failed to open stream". OK, so i downloaded the folder from symphony and that error disappears, but then there are other folders / files that it requires, some of which i cannot find on the web.

It is strange that it's not in the Carbon package in the first place!

So i am using PHP version 7.1
I downloaded the Carbon package from https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/releases
I followed the instruction on https://carbon.nesbot.com/ under the 'Direct download' tab
I have tried a lot of different versions of Carbon, current and older
I have zero idea why it is not allowing me to use it...

All i want is to use Carbon and install it in the traditional (outdated) way of including libraries.

I know using composer is a lot better, but do not want to get into the reasons of why i cannot use it in this thread please :)

Any help would be much appreciated

Guys i have very little knowledge of composer and dependencies, this may be the issue i am having...

Comment: It's all because of dependencies. What you experience that people don't re-invent the wheel, but include packages from other projects. Composer then fetches all that are needed (for Carbon in your case)

Comment: Oh ok i am pretty sure i get it now, in this case, how would it be possible to use Carbon without installing using composer? Do i have to include all dependencies? If so, how do i find out which it needs? I am sure a few years ago all i need to do was require a few files and i was good to go!

Comment: Why don't you just use composer? - Not a big deal. IT is moving forward and so should you. Anyway, to trick the system use composer on another project or system, load all dependencies and copy them into your project. Besides that, you could recursively go through your first dependency and find theirs... taking a while probably.

Comment: Thanks Dom, I am not in a position to use composer on my server, but i will use it (first time) locally then do it this way. I just thought i could use it in the old fashioned way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carbon really requires Composer at this point as it relies on dependencies. I would definitely take the time to learn and use Composer, it's great! You don't necessarily need it installed on the server provided you upload the files that Composer downloads for you in your local development environment.

With that said, you *could* use an old version (1.17.0) that will allow you to use it as a stand-alone with no dependencies *though I wouldn't recommend it*.

Download [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/1.17.0/src/Carbon/Carbon.php) Carbon file from the repo and save it as `carbon.php`.

Inside any of your `PHP` files:

```
<?php 

require 'your/path/to/carbon.php';
use Carbon\Carbon;

//Use Carbon

echo "Now: " . Carbon::now();
```

Comment: Thank you ProEvilz i think the time has come... I will :)

Comment: @Kobi Please accept the answer by pressing the green tick if it answered your initial question. :)